# Sending a STOMP frame through websocket

Tags: c++, qt, websocket, stomp

Since there's no webstomp (STOMP through Websocket) C++ implementation anywhere, I'm developing my own. I have a webstomp server set up already, and I've confirmed that it works using the javascript implementation of webstomp.

Now I'm relying on QT's implementation of websocket. I tested and works with a regular websocket. So now comes the implementation of STOMP. Looking at the STOMP frames the first frame I have to send could be something like this:

```
CONNECT
login: <username>
passcode: <passcode>

^@
```

With `^@`being the null-character. The problem I'm having is that no matter what I do, I can't seem to get **any** type of response from the server. I tried different encodings, different messages, different connect frames, etc. I was wondering if I was doing something wrong or if I was missing something. An example of the above frame looks like this:

```
void WebSTOMP::onConnected()
{
    if (m_debug)
        qDebug() << "WebSocket connected";
    connect(&m_webSocket, &QWebSocket::textMessageReceived,
            this, &EchoClient::onTextMessageReceived);
    std::string myMessage = "CONNECT \nlogin: test\npasscode : test\n\n\0";

    m_webSocket.sendTextMessage(QString::fromUtf8(myMessage.c_str()));
}
```

And then I never get a response back.

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: Funny, I was Googling Stomp over Websocket and found your github and then came here. I wonder if there is an existing implementation 3 years later, perhaps using boost::beast websocket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one to the length of the message due to the string's null character terminator

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. For the future: had to manually specify the length due to including a null character terminator.